# Reformat multiple dates in string using EXCEL VBA REGEX

Tags: regex, excel, vba, date, replace

I have an application which outputs queries in the form of copying text to the clipboard.

I've come up with parsing the text into arrays which I then populate back to excel.

the source string contains multiple instances of dates in the format "dd.mm.yyyy" I've been using find/replace on the output column to change this to "dd/mm/yyyy". I was wondering if it would be possible/faster to replace these in the string before parsing to the array by using regex.

```
strPattern = "(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\.]\d{4}"
strReplace = "$dd\/dd\/dddd"

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.test(sString) Then
        sString = regEx.Replace(sString, strReplace)
    End If
```

the end result is not what I was hoping for yet. I think the format of the 'strReplace' is wrong but I don't know regex well enough to fix it. the above was achieved by (too many) hours of web searches.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try `strReplace = "$1/$2/$3"` BTW, you do not need to test the string for a match. If there is no match, the string will not be modified.

Comment: Returns dd/mm/$3. So close

Comment: Yes, because you have no capturing group around `\d{4}`. Use `"(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0?[1-9]|1[012])\.(\d{4})"` pattern and `strReplace = "$1/$2/$3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
strPattern = "(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0?[1-9]|1[012])\.(\d{4})"
strReplace = "$1/$2/$3"

With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = strPattern
End With

sString = regEx.Replace(sString, strReplace)
```

Note:

- You can refer to a capturing group value using `$n` placeholder from the replacement string
- You do not need to use `[\.]`, it is the same as `\.` (or `[.]`)
- You do not need to test the string for a match. If there is no match, the string will not be modified.

A hint: if you want to match these strings as "whole word", use word boundaries `\b`:

```
strPattern = "\b(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0?[1-9]|1[012])\.(\d{4})\b"
```

Now, the date-like string will only be found when not enclosed with letters, digits or `_` chars.

Comment: many thanks for the quick response and helpful hints. problem solved.